# How to convert this function from C# to VB.net

Tags: lambda

Please I need your help. I tried and struggled to convert this code to vb.net but I couldn't. Even I used more than one code converter but the result is error with two lines of the code.

The following is the c# code:

```
public List<T> SortByPropertyName(string propertyName, bool ascending)
    {
        //Create a Lambda expression to dynamically sort the data.
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "N");

        var sortExpresseion = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>
            (Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(param, propertyName), typeof(object)), param);

        if (ascending)
        {
            return this.AsQueryable<T>().OrderBy<T, object>(sortExpresseion).ToList<T>();
        }
        else
        {
            return this.AsQueryable<T>().OrderByDescending<T, object>(sortExpresseion).ToList<T>();
        }
    }
```

The following is the VB converted code

```
        Public Function SortByPropertyName(propertyName As String, ascending As Boolean) As List(Of T)
        'Create a Lambda expression to dynamically sort the data.
        Dim param = Expression.Parameter(GetType(T), "N")

        Dim sortExpresseion = Expression.Lambda(Of Func(Of T, Object))(Expression.Convert(Expression.[Property](param, propertyName), GetType(Object)), param)

        If ascending Then
            Return Me.AsQueryable(Of T)().OrderBy(Of T, Object)(sortExpresseion).ToList(Of T)()
        Else
            Return Me.AsQueryable(Of T)().OrderByDescending(Of T, Object)(sortExpresseion).ToList(Of T)()
        End If
    End Function
```

The two lines of the code that I couldn't resolve are the lines in IF ELSE condition.

Thank you

I found the following code and I'm going to try it. It's in the following link:
http://p2p.wrox.com/book-asp-net-3-5-enterprise-application-development-visual-studio-2008-problem-design-solutio/73626-page-107-converting-vbulletin-net.html